# Is there a way in Excel to reference a cell range minus some cell? (As a function parameter)

Tags: excel-2007

Assume I have an Excel 2007 cell range of `B3:B50`.  Is there any way to specify instead `B3:B17+B19:B50`, or maybe `B3:B50-B18`?

Several sources say that `B3:B17,B19:B50` should work, but it doesn't work as a function parameter (for something like `CORREL`), since the comma is interpreted as separating parameters.

Answer (score -1):

I tried with a named range (which can have multiple points in the definition) and for `CORREL` got `#Value!` returned, but `SUM` worked as expected.
[image: Named Range]

you may have to test to see what functions will work

Comment: As the OP noted, Excel interprets the comma as an argument separator. SUM() and many other functions can take an unlimited number of arguments, and cells presented in an array are handled just the same as ones presented individually, delimited by commas. So I think that in this case SUM() isn't "working" in terms of interpreting the input as a single argument, which is what we're trying to accomplish. It's just that the "broken" interpretation happens to give the same result.

Comment: Actually, I believe the comma is the union operator in this context: [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/calculation-operators-and-precedence-HP010342223.aspx). There is no subtract range operator unfortunately.